# calculate $ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(kx\right) $

Tags: calculus

if $ x \notin \pi\mathbb{N} $ why the limit
 $ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(kx\right)  $

does not exist?

Comment: If it existed, what would it be?

Comment: No, that limit does not exist. Let kx = t and rewrite the limit. What do you get?

Comment: $\sin (kx)$ is an oscillating function in the interval $[-1,1]$, so for $k\to \infty$ the function's value is undefined.

Comment: How does infinity look like? What is $\infty +\pi/3$? And $\infty+\pi/2$ ?

Comment: @Inceptio $\infty+a=\infty $ where $a \in R$

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh: Haha. I'm asking the OP, man. Just to make him understand. I do understand what it is. And btw, $\infty+a \neq \infty$, cause:$\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: @Inceptio: I open your profile and see your answer then I surprised about your first comment hhhhhhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: f(x)=sin(x)]

so when $x\rightarrow \infty $ what you see ? is there any existed value for f(x)

note thate $-1\leq sin(kx)\leq 1$ :$k\in R$